# Multiple KDB+ ticker plant subscriptions in qPython

Tags: python, kdb, qpython

I'm working on a project where I have a few tables in kdb+ and I'd like to be able to subscribe to one or more of them at a time.

Now I looked at the [subscription example](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-examples.html#subscribing-to-tick-service) they provided and the subscription seems to be set on the connection itself. So as far as I understand for multiple subscriptions I would need multiple connections. Seems a bit tedious to me. Might there be a way to do this with just one connection?

Also, in the example mentioned above there is a thread for each subscription that's looping constantly and checking for new data. Is there any way to do this trigger-event-callback style?

Performance is a necessity, so I'm trying to explore whats possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, in the `main` definition, you can see a call to `.u.sub` with the tablename as a (symbol) argument. Make this call for each table to which you wish to subscribe. Ensure your handler in the `run` loop knows which table it's getting - a publisher calls `upd` on its subscribers, with `tablename` and `data` as the arguments.

With regards trigger-event-callback - you'll have to write your own (or wrap around other Python packages which do similar - see e.g. [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. They provided a Twisted example too, so I'm definitely going to check that out!